# Multithreaded GUI update() methods

Tags: multithreading, user-interface, model-view-controller, design-patterns, observers

I'm begginer in multithreading. I recently started to writing something like multithreaded observer. I need some clarification.

Let's say I'm working with Subject, and I'm changing its state. Then Observers (in example - GUI widgets) have to be notified, so they could perform the `update()` method.

And there is my **question**: how am i handling those `getValue()` performed by many Observers? If it's just a getter for some variable, do i have to run it in new thread? Does it require any locking?

Or mayby there is a metod to just send those new value to GUI thread, and letting widgets there access those value. And again, can it be a single loop, or do i have to create another threads for every widget to get those value?

Comment: It would be helpful if you could share some code along with this.

Answer (score 0):

That's a difficult subject. Here are couple of things that will guide and help you with it.

- Embrace eventual consistency. When one object updates on one thread, others will receive change notifications and update to the correct state *eventually*. Don't try to keep everything in sync all the time. Don't expect everything to be up to date all the time. Design your system to handle these situations. Check [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8Y-XPlXOWoA) video.
- Use immutability especially for collections. Reading and writing to a collection from multiple threads can result in disasters. Don't do it. Use immutable collections or use snapshotting. Basically one object that will called from multiple thread will return a snapshot of the state of the collection. when a notification for a change is received, the reader (GUI in your case) will request a snapshot of the new state and update it accordingly.
- Design rich [Models](https://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/domainModel.html). Don't use [AnemicModels](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/AnemicDomainModel.html) that have only `setters` and `getters` and let others manipulate them. Let the ***Model*** protect it's data and provide queries for it's state. Don't return mutable objects from properties of an object.
- Pass data that describes changes with change notifications. This way readers (GUI) may sync their state only from the change data without having to read the target object.
- Divide responsibility. Let the GUI know that it's single threaded and received notifications from the background. Don't add knowledge in your ***Model*** that it will be updated on a background thread and to know that it's called from the GUI and give it the responsibility of sending change requests to a specific thread. The ***Model*** should not care about stuff like that. It raises notifications and let subscribers handle them the way they need to. Let the GUI know that the change notification will be received on the background so it can transfer it to the UI thread.

Check [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QaE7r2aGsvM). It describes different way you can do multithreading.

You haven't shown any code or specified language, so I'll give you an example in pseudo code using a Java/C# like language.

```
public class FolderIcon {

    private Icon mIcon;

    public Icon getIcon() { return mIcon; }

    public FolderIcon(Icon icon) {
        mIcon = icon;
    }
}

public class FolderGUIElement : Observer {

    private Folder mFolder;
    private string mFolderPath;

    public FolderGUIElement(Folder folder) {

        mFolder = folder;
        mFolderPath = mFolder.getPath();

        folder.addChangeListener(this);
    }

    public void onSubjectChanged(change c) {

        if(c instanceof PathChange) {
            dispatchOnGuiThread(() => {
                handlePathChange((PathChange)change);
            });
        }
    }

    handlePathChange(PathChange change) {
        mFolderPath = change.NewPath;
    }
}

public class Folder : Subject {

    private string mPath;
    private FolderIcon mIcon;

    public string getPath() { return mPath; }

    public FolderIcon getIcon() { return mIcon; }

    public void changePath(string newPath) {
        mPath = patnewPath;
        notifyChanged(new PathChange(newPath));
    }

    public void changeIcon(FolderIcon newIcon) {
        mIcon = newIcon;
        notifyChanged(new IconChange(newIcon));
    }
}
```

Notice couple of things in the example.

1. We are using immutable objects from ***Folder***. That means that the GUI elements cannot get the value of `Path` or `FolderIcon` and change it thus affecting ***Folder***. When changing the icon we are creating a brand new ***FolderIcon*** object instead of modifying the old one. ***Folder*** itself is mutable, but it uses immutable objects for it's properties. If you want you can use fully immutable objects. A hybrid approach works well.
2. When we receive change notification we read the ***NewPath*** from the ***PathChange***. This way we don't have to call the ***Folder*** again.
3. We have `changePath` and `changeIcon` methods instead of `setPath` and `setIcon`. This captures the intent of our operations better thus giving our model behavior instead of being just a bag of `getters` and `setters`.

If you haven't read [Domain Driven Design](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321125215) I highly recommend it. It's not about multithreading, but on how to design rich models. It's in my list of books that every developer should read. On concept in DDD is [ValueObject](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/ValueObject.html). It's immutable and provide a great way to implement models and is especially useful in multithreaded systems.